Clarification on Gene Copy Number Calculation: Amplicon vs. Genome Size
I need clarification regarding gene copy number calculation. I used the amount of DNA extracted (90 ng/ml) to calculate the copy number of Pseudomonas sp. The amplicon size was 164 bp. I'm using the below formula for my calculations.
https://www.idtdna.com/pages/education/decoded/article/calculations-converting-from-nanograms-to-copy-number
which uses the length of dsDNA amplicon.
I addition, I found a webpage where they calculated the copy number using the whole genome as a template.
https://www.technologynetworks.com/tn/tools/copynumbercalculator --> In definition session there is an example.
Clarification 1: Is it correct to use the genome size instead of the amplicon size? Should I also use the genome size for my calculations?
Clarification 2: When I used the DNA amount and the amplicon size in the formula, the gene copy numbers were extremely high—eleven orders of magnitude higher than the reference, whereas many articles state that it should be closer to eight orders of magnitude. Is this number acceptable?


Clarification 1: Is it correct to use the genome size instead of the amplicon size? Should I also use the genome size for my calculations?

The ng concentration of DNA in your sample includes all of the DNA, not just your amplicon, so it depends on which sample type you're converting from. Are you measuring a genomic DNA extraction from bacterial cells or a purified PCR product? Either can technically be used for making a standard curve, but amplicons can be a little problematic. It's more common to use either the whole genome, or a plasmid with the target sequence cloned into it. Here's a guide on that. I sometimes purchase synthetic templates from IDT for my standards, but I always include about 30-40 flanking bases on either side of the target, so I have to include those bases in my copy number calculations.

Clarification 2: When I used the DNA amount and the amplicon size in the formula, the gene copy numbers were extremely high—eleven orders of magnitude higher than the reference, whereas many articles state that it should be closer to eight orders of magnitude. Is this number acceptable?

You're converting from weight to copy number. If you only use the amplicon sequence, you're assuming that 100% of the DNA sample consists of full-length copies of your amplicon (as in a purified PCR product). If it's genomic DNA, then you're actually converting to genome copies, of which only a tiny fraction contains your amplicon sequence. A Pseudomonas genome is at least 4 orders of magnitude larger than your amplicon, so around 99.99% of a gDNA sample is NOT your amplicon sequence (depending on whether or not there are multiple copies on the genome). That alone accounts for the differences your getting between the two calculation methods.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and clarifications! Your point about the distinction between amplicon and genomic DNA makes a lot of sense, and I now see why my copy number calculations were off. I was indeed converting from genomic DNA, so the massive difference in scale between the genome and my amplicon explains the inflated numbers. I’ll look into adjusting my calculations accordingly, as you suggested. Thanks again for your help!
